# Assembly: how to compare numbers of different signs?

Tags: assembly, x86, compare, nasm

G'evening. I'm doing a lab work on Assembly. I have to compare 3 numbers -8, -2 and 11 to get the greatest. I translated them in an additional code and represented them in hexadecimal notation. So I get wrong answer because -2 = FE > 11 = B. The question is how can I compare these numbers correctly?
I use nasm, x86.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compare instruction, as well as almost every arithmetic instructions will modify a set of flags in a status register.

The flags are modified independent of the intent of an instruction -- e.g. the  Parity Flag or Auxiliary Flag is modified regardless of the (rare) need to check the status of that flag.

When -2 is compared with 11, or 11 is subtracted from -2, the processor actually does not know that -2 is negative; instead 0xfe - 0x0b is computed, which does not overflow, thus CarryFlag == 0. Also because the result is not zero, ZeroFlag == 0 as well. And because 0xFE has a different sign than 0x0b, OverflowFlag == 0 too.

The different combinations of all these OF,ZF,CF map to higher level abstractions, such as `unsigned <= unsigned`, `any != any`, `signed > signed`. In Intel Architecture 'Below / Above' refer to unsigned compares and 'Greater / Less' refer to signed comparison -- also the same set of flags can refer to multiple abstractions, such as `JC`  (see http://unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html)

The subset of signed comparisons you probably need are then either `JG` or it's complement `JNG`, which stands for Jump Not Greater, which is equal to `JLE` or Jump Less or Equal.

In addition to conditional branch, x64 instruction set supports conditional set/move of a register and armv7 allows conditional execution of most instructions and armv8 allows conditional execution of some interesting sequences of instructions (like `a = b iff LessThan, else a = c + 1`).